# Horizontal ListView using sephiroth74 Library

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Here is the simplified example included in the  [HorizontalVariableListView library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
        items.add( "Text " + i);
    }
    mAdapter = new TestAdapter( this, R.layout.test_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items );
    listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled( true );
    listView.setFooterDividersEnabled( true );
    listView.setAdapter( mAdapter );
}
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    listView = (HListView) findViewById( R.id.hListView1 );
}
class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> mItems;
    public TestAdapter( Context context, int resourceId, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects ) {
        super( context, resourceId, textViewResourceId, objects );
        mItems = objects;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType( int position ) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        View view = super.getView( position, convertView, parent );
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.image ); // here the image is declared, but never used. 
        return view;
    }
}
... // other methods
```

I don't understand, where does he put the image for each item? I want to remove the for loop and set each items name and picture. how do i do that? Do i change the type of `items` and add pictures as int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting a day trying to get it done, i decided to go with HorizontalScrollView, setting 5 texts and 5 images, and filling them using switch case. If there are any other options, i would be glad to see them.